# How to track the current location of user when app enters in to background in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

I am new to swift can we track the current location of user when app enters in to back round  and parallely i want to send coordinates to my local server for every one minute .so i need solution for this it is possible or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28503990/ios-running-background-task-for-update-user-location-using-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361561/how-to-get-location-in-background-even-after-phone-restart-in-swift